# App Transport Security policy error after setting Arbitrary Loads to YES

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

I'm getting this error in my project

> The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection

this is a common problem I know but the answer is not

> adding App Transport Security Settings in info.plist and setting the Allow
>   Arbitrary Loads to YES

because I did that already and it works in every project I have, but for some reason the project I'm currently working on didn't work.
am not sure what I did wrong?

this is the info.plist under App Transport Security Settings

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>The domain</key>
            <dict>
                <key>**my domain here**</key>
                <dict/>
            </dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: "The domain" and "my domain here" are not valid values. Also the whole structure of your NSExceptionDomains dictionary is incorrect.

Comment: @matt can you explain more please ? what is wrong in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure is wrong:

```
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>The domain</key>
        <dict>
            <key>**my domain here**</key>
            <dict/>
        </dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

It should be:

```
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>The domain</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```